# How to set the domain and scale on an yaxis on a discreteBarChart nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using d3.js charts in one of my applications.
Here they are in this image
See [Charts](http://d.pr/i/Ogts)

For Y axis on Money chart (See in the Image), I want maximum value rounded to 400, no matter what maximum bar size is here it is $358.72, but I want to keep bar at 358.72 but on Y Axis it would be 400 Limit.

Code for it is here

```
tradesChart = [ 
      {
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
                        {
            "label" : "6E",
            "value" : 100       },
                    {
            "label" : "NG",
            "value" : 100       },
                    {
            "label" : "TF",
            "value" : 67        }        ]
      }
    ];
        nv.addGraph(function() {

      var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
          .x(function(d) { return d.label })
          .y(function(d) { return d.value/100 })
          .staggerLabels(true)
          .showValues(true)
          .valueFormat(d3.format('.0%'))

      chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format('d')(d*100) + '%'; });

      d3.select('#chart-trades svg')
        .datum(tradesChart)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
    });
```

Kindly Help me to solve this out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to modify the domain of the Y-axis scale. Usually it is derived from the maximum value of the data with a statement like the following:

```
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.v; }) ]);
```

In your case, you should modify it to be more like this instead:

```
yScale.domain([0, 400]);
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the maximum value from the data *or* a minimum static value, you could do something like the following:

```
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.v > 400 ? d.v : 400; }) ]);
```

A full example jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/69cwn/).

That's how to do it with D3.js, I'm not familiar with the venerable nvd3.js lib, so I'm not sure how to access the scale, but i'll take a look and see if I can find it.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but one more quetion, how can I dynamically set ranges using this. I already tried this `d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.v; })` but not working..

Comment: d3.max will work for setting the maximum value in the data. However, if you want to use the max of the actual data *or* a static value (400 for example) you could do it with something like:

yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.v > 400 ? d.v : 400; }) ]);
I updated the fiddle to show this technique at http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/69cwn/32/

Answer (score 1):

I use nvd3 and for me this worked instead:

```
nv.models.discreteBarChart().yDomain([0,400])
```

I could'nt get it to work with `yScale.domain`

Answer (score 0):

Force Y

List of numbers to Force into the Y scale (ie. 0, or a max / min, etc.). The numbers tell the d3.js the values to use in the scale, rather than d3.js determining the values.

Datatype: Array of Numbers (i.e. [0, 50]

http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html