# set maximum x and y axis range NVD3

Tags: graph, nvd3.js

I am trying to plot the line graph using NVD3. But the issue I am facing is that the maximum values of x and y axis get adjusted automatically depending on the data provided. But I don't want this default behavior, I want to preset the maximum values for X and Y axis. Is there an option to do so in NVD3?

[Tried this domain approach but didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840759/how-to-set-the-domain-and-scale-on-an-yaxis-on-a-discretebarchart-nvd3-js)

Comment: For the yAxis have you tried `chart.forceY([minValue, maxValue]);` ?

Comment: it worked.. thanks. and can you please tell where to look for these in the future? coz I didn't find them in the API documentation present on github

Comment: I have added the answer so you can accept, and marks this question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `chart.forceY([minValue, maxValue])`.

NVD3 is built on D3 so if you are to look deep, it's best to look into the [D3 Api](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference).