# d3js maximum and minimum on x scale.

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to control maximum and minimum of x scale on this graph made with d3js. 
The graph is constructed with a following code:

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.twoLinesWithFocusChart()
            .x(function(d) {
                return d[0]
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return d[1]
            })
            .clipEdge(true);

        chart.xAxis
            .orient("bottom") // this adds a label to the axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d))
            });

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Values:') // this adds a label to the axis
            .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

        chart.x2Axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d))
            });

        d3.select('#' + svgChartId + ' svg')
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(500).call(chart);


        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);


        return chart;
    });
```

Best regards.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840759/how-to-set-the-domain-and-scale-on-an-yaxis-on-a-discretebarchart-nvd3-js) or Try `chart.forceX([minValue, maxValue]);`

Comment: Thank you. Can you post this as a answer? I must accept answer to me question.

Comment: Which code worked for you ? So I can Add the correct answer

Comment: chart.forceX([minValue, maxValue])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simillar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840759/how-to-set-the-domain-and-scale-on-an-yaxis-on-a-discretebarchart-nvd3-js) by using :-

`xScale.domain([minValue,maxValue]);`

or you could try using :-

```
chart.forceX([minValue,maxValue]);
```

Hope it helps.